# Why is expression not evaluated completely?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, evaluation

I have a simple sum of complex numbers. In my example their sum is zero.

```
sum = Total[{1 , E^(2*I/3*Pi) , E^((4*I)/3*Pi)}]
Print[sum]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/7@4NFfBViEkvyQxJ7raUEFHwTVOw0jLU99YKyBTE8LVMNHy1IQI1MZyBRRl5pVEA7XF/v8PAA)

When computing this sum, I just get back this "symbolic" expression:

```
1 + E^((-2*I)/3*Pi) + E^((2*I)/3*Pi)
```

(I already learned that this can be reduced to a single number using `Simplify[]` to get the result I expect.)

But when I replace this list of complex numbers with e.g. a list of integers `{1,2,3}` it does get evaluated to a single number.

I didn't understand why these two cases behave differently, so can you explain why I get an expression back for the first case and a fully simplified number in the second case?

Comment: Is there some reason to expect any result other than the one indicates? Stated differently, what result is expected from `1+ E^((-2*I)/3*Pi)+E^((2*I)/3*Pi)`? Or, for that matter, from just adding the last two terms: `E^((-2*I)/3*Pi)+E^((2*I)/3*Pi)`?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau As there exists a much simpler representation I expected Mathematica to find that, just as it finds the most "simple" representation of a fraction or a sum. (I mean it would not return a fraction like `4/10` or a sum like `1+2+3`.) Of course such simple sums might be easier to compute, but the original sum that I was referring to was also just an algebraic expression which are computationally not too difficult to simplify.

Comment: Arithmetic involves basic evaluation so for example entering `1+2+3` will give `6`. But finding "simplest" forms in general is outside the scope of the core evaluator. Functions such as `Simplify` can be used for this purpose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Exact numeric expressions are treated symbolically, and there are a very limited number of transformations that will be applied automatically. Adding "actual numbers" (see [`NumberQ[]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberQ.html)) is one such transformation that occurs.  But `E^((-2*I)/3*Pi)` is not converted to a number, unless such a transformation is explicitly requested (as is done by `Simplify[]`, `ComplexExpand[]`, and so forth).  A similar thing happens with the following:

```
Total@ArcTan@Range@3
(*  π/4 + ArcTan[2] + ArcTan[3]  *)

FullSimplify[%]
(*  π  *)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
sum = Total[{1, E^(2*I/3*Pi), E^((4*I)/3*Pi)}]

(* 1+E^(-((2 I π)/3))+E^((2 I π)/3) *)
```

Using machine precision, the sum is not identically zero

```
sum // N

(* 4.44089*10^-16+0. I *)
```

In fact, **basic** symbolic and numerical methods used internally do not show that `sum` has value zero

```
sum // PossibleZeroQ

(* PossibleZeroQ::ztest1: Unable to decide whether numeric quantity 
    1-(-1)^(1/3)+(-1)^(2/3) is equal to zero. Assuming it is.

True *)
```

Consequently, `sum` does not automatically evaluate to zero. More robust methods are required such as

```
#@sum& /@ {Simplify, ComplexExpand, RootReduce}

(* {0,0,0} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sum = Total[{1, E^(2*I/3*Pi), E^((4*I)/3*Pi)}] // ExpToTrig
(*0*)
```